# Connect main/root domain to hashnode blog, not subdomain

Tags: dns, netlify

I bought and registered a domain via Netlify.com. I have an account at Hashnode that I succefully connected to my Netlify domain. The problem is that it is connected to a subdomain, not my root domain.

Domain: [www.davekjellmarong.com](http://www.davekjellmarong.com)
SubDomain: [www.blog.davekjellmarong.com](http://www.blog.davekjellmarong.com)

When I go to [www.davekjellmarong.com](http://www.davekjellmarong.com), I want it to display my hashnode blog. But now, you need to go to [www.blog.davekjellmarong.com](http://www.blog.davekjellmarong.com) to reach my blog. I do not want the subdomain.

I used these info to add the custom domain.

- Type:cname
- Value: hashnode.network

On netlify.com I added the subdomain with the values above. I have tried to edit the main domain settings there, but that’s not possible.

Does any have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your hashnode blog settings domains section and delete your current sub-domain.
Then add your custom domain.

Now, you have to map your domain to Hashnode by adding the following DNS record.

|  | Host name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A record | @ | 76.76.21.21 |

And for [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com),

|  | Host name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CNAME record | www | hashnode.network |

Now you're all set with your new custom domain.